# Modal message as javascript alert?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, modal-dialog, alert

Im pretty new in Modal Alerts World and im trying to make modal messages as alerts inside a javascript function, first change the div innerHtml and then show the message i don't know if is posible.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function myalert() {

 alert("My alert");

}

</script>
```

Im working with that example: http://jsfiddle.net/Hu55H/

As i said i need it like a onclick function, because i need to call it by javascript (like alerts).

Im just asking if is possible to do it.

Hope you all can help me!

Comment: What is the question? The fiddle seems to work

Comment: Yes fiddle works, but it call it by href="" i need to call it by javascript like onlick="javascript:somefunction()"

Comment: go to [jquery UI dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-message)

Comment: do some research on google.

Comment: Just FYI, putting javascript: in the onclick handler is unecessary.  the Onclick takes JavaScript by default. The "javascript:" protocol is from back in the Web 1.0 days when AJAX wasn't yet a thing. Hope this helps.

Comment: Wow i didin't know it jmort, thanks i wont use it again.

Comment: Actually the javascript: LABEL (it is only a protocol in the href) is only necessary in IE when the first script on the page is VBScript since that will set the default scripting language on the page to VBScript instead of JScript. That will give errors in inline event handlers that are using JavaScript/JScript specific calls if javascript: is not specified. Additionally to removing the label, you need to return false in a link's onclick event if you want to stay on the page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need this, I think:

```
$('selector').dialog({
                resizable: false,
                height: 300,
                modal: true,
                draggable: false,
                buttons: {
                    YES: function () {
                        //Code

                    },
                    Cancel: function () {
                        //Code
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: Im pretty new on jquery, if you can link it to JSfiddle i'll understand a little bit more, by the way thanks a lot for answering.